# Get substring after the first = symbol in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Purely out of curiosity, is there a more elegant way to simply get the substring after the first `=` symbol in a string? The following works to give back `name=bob`:

```
string = "option=name=bob"
string[string.index('=')+1..-1]
```

It just doesn't feel very Ruby. This also works:

```
string.split('=', 2)[1]
```

Again, not very elegant especially since `split` is doing extra unnecessary work. Are regular expressions the answer? I felt this was a little overkill for the simplicity of finding a single character position in a string:

```
string.match('=(.*)')[1]
```

I have to imagine this is an extremely common situation, isn't there a `string.after('=')` type method? Does Ruby on Rails provide something like this given the frequency this kind of operation is used over the web?

***UPDATE***: Forgot to mention the situation when the symbol is not found, `nil` or empty string should be returned. But the regular expression mechanism and `.index` method require an extra check for that (so less elegant).

Comment: Small regular expressions on small strings are really _really_ fast.

Comment: @AlexWayne - that makes me feel better :), but then I guess I have to account for the situation that the = symbol isn't found.

Comment: "more elegant way..." questions should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Not exactly `.after`, but quite close to:

```
string.partition('=').last
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-partition

Comment: yes, very similar to `split`, I like your use of `.last` vs `[1]` (or in the `partition` case it would be `[2]`)

Answer (score 14):

There's also this way:

```
string.partition('=')[2]
```

And this one:

```
string.sub(/.*?=/, '')
```

I think I prefer the regexp way you mentioned, though.

Comment: the `.sub` way has the advantage over `.match` that it works (if you want the original string) even if the symbol isn't found.

Comment: Note that the regex version fails if the string contains `"foo\nbar=baz"`. In such a scenario you are left with `'foobaz'`. `.` doesn't match newline characters, to enable multiline matching use the `m` flag. `/.*?=/m` does work for strings with newline characters.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not the Ruby-way (it's a bit cryptic), but you could do this:

```
string[/=/]
$'
=> "name=bob"
```

or

```
/=/ =~ string
$'
=> "name=bob"
```

`$'` is a global holding the string **after** a successful match. It's `nil` if nothing is matched, too!

Comment: wow, didn't know there was a global variable holding this. And this works properly when the symbol isn't found.

Comment: Good. Now go and forget it again ;)

Comment: @Thomas - :). What issues arise from using `$'`? Not very pretty.. potential for conflicts in a Rails app?

Comment: To make it clearer, you could include the `english` standard library and use `$POSTMATCH` instead of `$'`. That's not too bad, imo.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use String#match

You can use a regular expression with positive lookbehind to find your match. For example:

```
string = "option=name=bob"
string.match /(?<==).*/
# => #<MatchData "name=bob">
```

#### Use Match Variables to Access Result

Even if you haven't assigned the match data to a variable, Ruby will store it in special [match variables](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/MatchData.html) for you.

```
$&
# => "name=bob"
```

Answer (score 1):

`split(char)` is another function which can be used. 
For instance, we want to get substring before char ':' from "answer:computer" then, we can use `"answer:computer".split(':')[0]`.So, we would get result as "answer".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `string.split('=', 2)[1]` you could use [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).

```
# assuming your string represents a key=value pair
key, value = string.split('=', 2)
```

Although this solution does not fit in one-liners I do find it pretty clean.