# Is there a function available in ruby where the part after regex match can be returned?

Tags: ruby

I have a string say its in the below format.

```
2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263825 (Followed by strings)
2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263826 (Followed by strings)
```

Do we have a function to return only the (Followed by strings) part. If we have a pattern for the first part

```
^\w*\s*(?<time_var>\w*\/\w*\/\w*\s\w*:\w*:\w*.\w*)\s\w*
```

The above pattern matches the timestamp followed by number.
I found this [Get substring after the first = symbol in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073743/get-substring-after-the-first-symbol-in-ruby) but didn't help actually! Am i doing anything wrong here?

```
irb(main):001:0> line = "2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263825 (Followed by strings)"
=> "2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263825 (Followed by strings)"
irb(main):002:0> line.partition('^\w*\s*(?<time_var>\w*\/\w*\/\w*\s\w*:\w*:\w*.\w*)\s\w*').last
=> ""
irb(main):003:0> line.partition('^\w*\s*(?<time_var>\w*\/\w*\/\w*\s\w*:\w*:\w*.\w*)\s\w*')
=> ["2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263825 (Followed by strings)", "", ""]
```

And without last function it matching the whole string?

Comment: Do you wish to verify the string begins with a valid timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`MatchData#post_match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/MatchData.html#method-i-post_match) returns the string after the actual match:

```
pattern = /^\w*\s*(?<time_var>\w*\/\w*\/\w*\s\w*:\w*:\w*.\w*)\s\w*/
line = "2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263825 (Followed by strings)"

line.match(pattern, &:post_match)
#=> " (Followed by strings)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
line = "2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263825 (Followed by strings)"
l = line.gsub(/^\w*\s*(?<time_var>\w*\/\w*\/\w*\s\w*:\w*:\w*.\w*)\s\w*/, "").lstrip
# l ==> "(Followed by strings)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regexp capture:

```rb
str = <<~STR
  2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263825 (Followed by strings)
  2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263826 (Followed by strings)
STR

tstamp_line_rgx = %r{\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{3} \d+ (.*)}

str.lines.map do |line|
  line[tstamp_line_rgx, 1]
end
```

I have a slightly different regex (I think yours might work too), but the important part is `(.*)`, which captures "anything after the timestamps + pid, to the end of the line", and it's referenced by the `1` in `string_variable[regex, 1]` because it's the `1`st parenthesized capture group.

You can see more clearly the regex capture groups etc when using it "directly" (as opposed to the `string[regex, capture_num]` syntax):

```rb
[12] pry(main)> a_string = "2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263826 (Followed by strings)"
=> "2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263826 (Followed by strings)"
[13] pry(main)> tstamp_line_rgx.match(a_string)
=> #<MatchData "2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263826 (Followed by strings)" 1:"(Followed by strings)">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply your pattern is working fine seems to be some issue with mine?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\K` to **k**eep the string after the regex:

```rb
regex = %r(^\w*\s*(?<time_var>\w*\/\w*\/\w*\s\w*:\w*:\w*.\w*)\s\w*)
'2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263825 (Followed by strings)'.match(/#{regex}\K.*/).to_s
# => " (Followed by strings)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your timestamp has a very definite pattern. Among other things,

```
'2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263825'.size
  #=> 30
```

One therefore could write:

```
str = '2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263825 the cat and the hat'

time_stamp = str[0,30]
  #=> "2020/07/08 16:30:03.919 263825" 
remainder  = str[30..-1].strip
  #=> "the cat and the hat"
```

If you wish to be on the safe side by confirming it is a valid time stamp, you could do the following.

```
time_stamp_str = time_stamp[0,23]
  #=> "2020/07/08 16:30:03.919" 
time_stamp_supp = time_stamp[23..-1]
  #=> " 263825" 
time_stamp_supp.match?(/\A \d+\z/)
  #=> true
```

```
require 'time'

def time_stamp_valid?(time_stamp_str)
  rv = DateTime.strptime(time_stamp_str, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%L') rescue false
  !!rv
end
```

```
time_stamp_valid?(time_stamp_str)
  #=> true
```

Here

```
rv #=> #<DateTime: 2020-07-08T16:30:03+00:00 ((2459039j,59403s,919000000n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

See [DateTime::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) and (for formatting directives) [DateTime#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime).  `strptime` raises an exception if the string does not represent a valid date, in which case `time_stamp_valid?` rescues the exception in-line and returns `false`.

`!!` merely converts *truthy* objects (here a `DateTime` object) to `true` and converts *falsy* objects (`nil` and `false`) to `false`.

Verifying a time stamp in this way is preferable to using a regular expression as the latter can give incorrect results. For example, most regexes would not be able to determine whether Feb. 29, 2000 is a valid date (though it can be done). Moreover, this approach is so much easier than crafting a regex that does only a fair job of evaluating date-time stings for correctness.

Above all, do not use use `parse` as it can be quite unpredicable. For example: `DateTime.parse("She thought that maybe he was the killer after all") #=> #<DateTime: 2020-05-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2458971j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`.

Comment: Thanks @Cary Swoveland